# How to use m with the ed function in a Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I am trying to move a line inside of a file using a bash script but I keep running into errors like unknown command and file or directory not found. the best I've been able to come up with is:

```
sed -i '4m9' "$argument"
```

Where $argument is the file, 4 is the line that I want to move and 9 is where I want it to go but it still just gives me errors. Is there something with sed that I am missing?

Comment: [tag:sed] is not [tag:ed].

Comment: I don't see from your question, what the content of the variable `argument` is, and what the exact wording of the error message would be. If you have a question about `sed`, I suggest that you also tag your question with the _sed_ tag. Finally, it is not clear what the `ed` in the title of your question refers to. It would also be helpful if you could provide a (**small**) input file which would demonstrate the problem.

Comment: `sed '4{h;d};9G' my-file` will do it. Or, run `ed my-file`, then at the ed prompt type:`4m9` to move, `w` to write the change, and `q` to quit.

Comment: `sed` doesn't have an `m` command, since you can't arbitrarily move lines forward or backwards. (`sed` doesn't assume a file, only a *stream* of incoming bytes.) `ed` (a *file* editor) itself is usually more appropriate than `sed -i`. People are just more familiar with `sed` and overlook the existence of `ed`.

Comment: `printf '4m9\nwq\n' | ed "$argument"`. `ed` takes the file to edit as its argument and reads a script from standard input.